# When i use Spring Boot with shiro , Spring Boot Actuator doesnt publish jvm metric

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shiro, spring-boot-actuator

I use Spring Boot with Shiro , but i starting Application and navigating to /actuator/metrics displays a list of available meter names:

```
{
    names: [
        "http.server.requests",
        "jdbc.connections.max",
        "jdbc.connections.min"
    ]
}
```

Just 3 items!!!

Then , i shield shiro config :

```
//@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {
      ...
}
```

I starting Application again and i get all:

```
{
names: [
"jvm.memory.max",
"process.files.max",
"jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
"tomcat.cache.hit",
"system.load.average.1m",
"tomcat.cache.access",
"jvm.memory.used",
"jvm.gc.max.data.size",
"jdbc.connections.max",
"jdbc.connections.min",
"jvm.gc.pause",
"jvm.memory.committed",
"system.cpu.count",
"logback.events",
"tomcat.global.sent",
"jvm.buffer.memory.used",
"tomcat.sessions.created",
"jvm.threads.daemon",
"system.cpu.usage",
"jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
"tomcat.global.request.max",
"tomcat.global.request",
"tomcat.sessions.expired",
"jvm.threads.live",
"jvm.threads.peak",
"tomcat.global.received",
"process.uptime",
"tomcat.sessions.rejected",
"process.cpu.usage",
"tomcat.threads.config.max",
"jvm.classes.loaded",
"jvm.classes.unloaded",
"tomcat.global.error",
"tomcat.sessions.active.current",
"tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
"jvm.gc.live.data.size",
"tomcat.servlet.request.max",
"tomcat.threads.current",
"tomcat.servlet.request",
"process.files.open",
"jvm.buffer.count",
"jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
"tomcat.sessions.active.max",
"tomcat.threads.busy",
"process.start.time",
"tomcat.servlet.error"
]
}
```

I want to use both Actuator and Shiro.
Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Can you share your Pom.xml and other config if any.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem: 

When i use shiro ,i injected mybatis's xxxMapper in my CustomRealm.java file , because I need to get data from the database through mybatis.

I use @Autowired injected mybatis's xxxMapper , i try to do not injected mybatis's xxxMapper , so I deleted the annotation, although I can't get the data from the database.Unexpectedly, after I deleted the annotation /actuator/metrics displays a list of available meter names!!!

Comment: I think it may be due to the loading order of Beans.

Comment: I will try to inject it by hand injection [mybatis mapper] tomorrow. [mybatis mapper] only needs to be manually injected in the specific method of loading database data.

Answer (score 0):

As I expected, this problem is caused by the loading order of the beans.

I used Shiro in the project.

Shiro's verification method used MyBatis to read data from the database.

**I used @Autowired for MyBatis' Mapper file, which caused the Actuator metrics related beans to not be assembled by SpringBoot** (I don't know what the specific reason is).

**So i disabled the automatic assembly of the Mapper file by manual assembly**.

The code is as follows:

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        SpringContextUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanId) throws BeansException {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanId);
    }
}
```

Then

```
StoreMapper userMapper = (UserMapper) SpringContextUtil.getBean("userMapper");
UserModel userModel = userMapper.findUserByName(name);
```

The problem can be solved for the time being. This is just a stopgap measure, but at the moment I have no better way.